# How to create Django models from oracle table-synonyms using inspectdb command

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using **Oracle legacy database** from which I am creating models using `inspectdb` command(`inspectdb table_name`) for existing tables. But this command is only working for **tables and views not for table-synonym**.

Please correct me if I am wrong:

There is no way to specify schema with table name as : `[schema].[table_name]` in Django framework.

So, I found a solution on the given link
[How to access tables from a different schema in oracle 11g using django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543466/how-to-access-tables-from-a-different-schema-in-oracle-11g-using-django)

I created a **private table-synonym in oracle db** and used `inspectdb [synonym_name]` command but was unable to inspect the synonym. This command working fine for table and view but not for synonym.

[image: inspectdb WASTE2 error-screenshot]